# Upload Image and display preview

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I created a function to upload images, however I am having trouble viewing these images ...
My problem: When I click the button to select an image, I select an image and would like it to fill the entire box.

Image 1 illustrates the problem (image fills the entire border)

[image: image 1]

Problem 2: When I select more than one image, they are all in line in the giant box ... the goal was to have 1 image filling the big box and the remaining ones filling the small boxes.
Image 2 illustrates the problem.

[image: image 2]

In this image below I illustrate better what I intend.
[image]

Please someone help me !

[MY CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/Harry_x21/pen/VwwpYgE)

**Javascript**

```
var drop = $("input");
    drop.on('dragenter', function (e) {
      $(".drop").css({
        "border": "4px dashed #09f",
        "background": "rgba(0, 153, 255, .05)"
      });
      $(".cont").css({
        "color": "#09f"
      });
    }).on('dragleave dragend mouseout drop', function (e) {
      $(".drop").css({
        "border": "3px dashed #DADFE3",
        "background": "transparent"
      });
      $(".cont").css({
        "color": "#8E99A5"
      });
    });



    function handleFileSelect(evt) {
      var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object

      // Loop through the FileList and render image files as thumbnails.
      for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {

        // Only process image files.
        if (!f.type.match('image.*')) {
          continue;
        }

        var reader = new FileReader();

        // Closure to capture the file information.
        reader.onload = (function (theFile) {
          return function (e) {
            // Render thumbnail.

            var span = document.createElement('span');
            span.innerHTML = ['<img class="thumbs" src="', e.target.result,
              '" title="', escape(theFile.name), '"/>'].join('');
            document.getElementById('list').insertBefore(span, null);
          };
        })(f);

        // Read in the image file as a data URL.
        reader.readAsDataURL(f);
      }
    }

    $('#files').change(handleFileSelect);
```

Comment: Would you like to use the Angular framework instead? or do you really need just Vanilla JS?

Comment: @mtorreblanca May be in JS, if you can help me thank you very much. If you have an angular solution, I also accept

Comment: let me figure out how to implement it only with JS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please review this codepen approach.

You need to add this things:

```
 <div class="Upcard">
          <div class="card-block" id="2">
          </div>
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
/* Images Module */
img {
    /* bootstrap was overalaping this feature */
    width: 100% !important;
}

.card-block> img {
    height: 100% !important;
}
```

JS modify:

```
var enter = false;

 reader.onload = (function (theFile) {
            return function (e) {
                // Render thumbnail.
                if (!enter) {
                    var list = document.getElementById('list');
                    list.innerHTML = ['<img class="thumbs" src="', e.target.result,
                        '" title="', escape(theFile.name), '"/>'].join('');
                    enter = true;
                } else {
                    // you need to loop here, Im sorry I do not remember the looping thing, but this is the approach... 
                    var card = document.getElementById('2');
                    card.innerHTML = ['<img class="thumbs" src="', e.target.result,
                        '" title="', escape(theFile.name), '"/>'].join('');
                }

            };
        })(f);
```

https://codepen.io/MarchWhitetower/pen/yLLMerV

Comment: I had some difficulties implementing the for cycle. If you inserted 3 picture, it would insert into large box 1, then skip small box 1 and put it in 2.

Comment: Is it possible to drag the images between the boxes (change their positions) or remove them?

Comment: I already tested some drag functions and are not working .. working with images is painful